# ACF: Custom Field for Users & Orders - How to Copy Over?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom field set up for users that assigns a rep to their account. I have created the same field for the orders page so we can assign the orders to their sales rep. When a new order is placed, I'm wanting it to update the Sales Rep field based on the data found under the User info. Is there a simple Get function I can use to accomplish this?

I'm still a novice, so I've read a collection of message boards and haven't been able to find quite what I'm looking for.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `get_field()` function provided by Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) to retrieve the sales rep assigned to the user and update the sales rep field for the order. Add the below code to your active theme functions.php file.

```
// Update sales rep field for new orders
function update_sales_rep_for_order($order_id) {
    // Get the user ID associated with the order
    $user_id = get_post_meta($order_id, '_customer_user', true);

    // Check if user ID is available
    if ($user_id) {
        // Get the sales rep assigned to the user
        $sales_rep = get_field('sales_rep', 'user_' . $user_id);

        // Update the sales rep field for the order
        if ($sales_rep) {
            update_post_meta($order_id, 'sales_rep', $sales_rep);
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_new_order', 'update_sales_rep_for_order');
```

**Note:** Please ensure that you modify the ACF field key and the meta key in the code to match your desired keys.